# PHP mySQL turning a string into a png is only working for the first image

Tags: php, mysql, string, image, blob

So I am trying to get a bunch of photos to appear that are saved in a mysql database. With the code I am using, the page displays just the very first photo in the database with nothing else. There are 5 different photos and I don't know where they are going. If someone could help that would be great. My code is here:

```
    while($imageRow = mysql_fetch_array($imageResults)){
        $data = $imageRow['image_data'];
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        if ($im !== false) {
            header('Content-Type: image/png');
            imagepng($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }
    }
```

Comment: standard http does not allow MULTIPLE different items to be downloaded in a single request. the mime-style multiple sections options never caught on. you have to do ONE request for each image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers will only display one image per page.

You could try:

```
while($imageRow = mysql_fetch_array($imageResults)){
    $data = $imageRow['image_data'];
    print '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$data.'" />';
}
```

That's untested, but something like that should work.

A better way would be to store the image file on the disk and store the location in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could either insert them into mysql as in blob type or simply upload the file to a folder and insert the file name into the database (I assume you just dont create random folders for each instance therefore you would know the destination path already)